# ajax request sometime fails on live site but never fails on Dev server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am submitting a form using ajax. Form is consist of some textboxes, textareas etc (string data) and a file as well. I am sending the form as javascript `FormData()`. However, I am using two servers i.e. a DEV server and a LIVE server. On DEV Server, the ajax request doesn't fail at all. However, on LIVE server, the ajax request sometimes fails.

How to become confident that the ajax request never fails on LIVE site as well.

Following is my ajax request.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("consider all my data here from form",data);
$.ajax({
                url : 'abc.com/controller/function&token='+token,
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loader").show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loader").hide();
                },
                success: function(json){
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    console.log(json);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Something went wrong while updating chapter info. Please, refresh and try again.");
                }

            });
```

Comment: It would be useful if you also posted any errors your browser console and/or server logs spit out on the live site? If the failing is random as far as you understand, you could re-try the request 3 times or something before showing a failure message?

Comment: Actually, i don't have access to Live server. I am a developer and I am using Dev Server. On, Dev server, I am not getting this Ajax request Fail at all. Same code is on both servers.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much to go from without any indication of what the failure is. Does the `console.log(error)` produce anything useful? Is there an option to ask the server admin for the copy of the Apache / PHP error logs?

Comment: I think that the problem should be in the server, but there could be many reasons for it, server setup, server code. May be you are sending the wrong data and the server fails to process it. You should provide more information.

Comment: I tried to upload bigger files and it gave me "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET for [link](http://example.com/controller/function&token=asdas232sada23). How to over come this error. This error is coming very rarely, not always.

Comment: How to become satisfied that it never fails? Any suggestions.